# Got back Hibernation option, but cannot resume from Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my Ubuntu 12.04, the hibernation option was working well and fine. However, I installed Debian on another partition recently and when I again tried to boot to Ubuntu, I got a message on the boot splash screen saying :

> The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present. Continue to
>   wait; or press s to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.

After logging into Ubuntu, I find that my hibernation option has gone missing.

Is there anyway to recover the hibernation option?

EDIT: I solved the disk drive problem and I got the hibernation option back. When I did "sudo pm-hibernate", my system went to hibernation. However, when powering on again, it booted up normally and thus there was no effect of hibernation.

How can this be rectified?

EDIT1: System - Lenovo ideapad s10-2.

[image]

EDIT2: /etc/fstab

[image]

EDIT3: Screenshot of my hard disk.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you have installed Debian in a way that it uses it's own separate swap partition. If you have not, I would suggest doing so (create another swap partition and change the `/etc/fstab` files accordingly), because too different operating systems writing to the same swap partition may discard hibernation data stored on the partition by the other OS.

Then you have to ensure that the OS you want to use hibernation on (usually both), writes to the correct partition. This is configured in the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file. You have to put the UUID of the correct swap partition in there (use `sudo blkid /dev/$device_name` to get the UUID). Finally you need to update the initial ramdisk:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

That should fix it.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. Thank you, I got my hibernation back. :)

Comment: I, too had problems resuming from hibernate. After having somehow changed the UUID of my swap partition, my system would not resume no matter what I seemed to do. Fixing my */etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume*, by copy-pasting the UUID from `sudo blkid` seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, hibernate doesn't work in many cases, which can cause you to lose data if you expect your documents and applications to re-open when you switch your computer back on. Therefore, hibernate is disabled by default.

### Test if hibernate works

*Note* : **Always save your work before hibernating**
You should save all of your work before hibernating the computer, just in case something goes wrong and your open applications and documents cannot be recovered when you switch on the computer again.

You can use the command line to test if hibernate works on your computer.

1. Open the Terminal by pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by searching for
   terminal in the Dash.
2. Type `sudo pm-hibernate` into the terminal and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   Enter your password when prompted.
3. After you computer turns off, switch it back on. Did your open applications re-open?

**If hibernate doesn't work, check if your swap partition is at least as large as your available RAM.**

### Enable hibernate

If the hibernate test works, you can continue to use the `sudo pm-hibernate` command when you want to hibernate.

You can also enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use your favorite text editor to create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. Add the following to the file and save:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate; org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Restart and hibernation is back!

Or run `killall unity-panel-service` to just reset the menu.

Some users will then need to run `sudo update-grub` to get the hibernate option to be available in the power menu. Some users may also have to at least log out then log in to get it to appear in the (upper right) power menu.

*Source* : [Ubuntu Docs - Power Hibernate](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

*Source* : [Ubuntu Wiki - Debugging Kernel Hibernate](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `nobootwait` option to the `/etc/fstab`, something like this:

`/dev/sda1       /               ext4   rw,nobootwait 0       1`

Comment: Could you clarify that? My /etc/fstab has the following entry for my swap partition: # swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=08a07061-165b-4f0a-87c3-470a02d1ea4c none            swap    sw              0       0                       
Should I change "sw" to "rw,nobootwait"?

Comment: You need to add it to your root mountpoint, not the swap. Post your full fstab, and I will post you the updated version.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: errors=remount-ro,nobootwait

Answer (score 0):

When going into hibernate, a full image of you RAM is copied to swap. So most of the time people have problems with hibernation not working, their swap is too small.

You need at least as much swap as you have RAM. If you have a lot of RAM, set [swappiness=0](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F). So if you have 8GB of RAM, use 8.5 or 9GB of swap. If you have 4GB of RAM, 6GB of swap is a good number.

Comment: I have 1GB RAM and I have 1.95GB swap space. Updated question with a screenshot of my hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Linux including Ubuntu should have swap space 2x of ram installed.

Some how my custom build computer configuration is not able to use hibernate tho I have more then enough swap space.
[image]

If you think your swap is slowing you down you can use this script I found on the internet.
It cleans swap.

```
#!/bin/bash

free_data="$(free)"
mem_data="$(echo "$free_data" | grep 'Mem:')"
free_mem="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $4}')"
buffers="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $6}')"
cache="$(echo "$mem_data" | awk '{print $7}')"
total_free=$((free_mem + buffers + cache))
used_swap="$(echo "$free_data" | grep 'Swap:' | awk '{print $3}')"

echo -e "Free memory:\t$total_free kB ($((total_free / 1024)) MB)\nUsed swap:\t$used_swap kB ($((used_swap / 1024)) MB)"
if [[ $used_swap -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Congratulations! No swap is in use."
elif [[ $used_swap -lt $total_free ]]; then
    echo "Freeing swap..."
    swapoff -a
    swapon -a
else
    echo "Not enough free memory. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I have 2x swap space available. Thank you for the suggestion.